# Using Google Composer to run Bigquery query

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am new To Google composer and Apache airflow.

I am trying to query Bigquery by creating a DAG.

```
import datetime

import airflow
from airflow.operators import bash_operator


from airflow.contrib.operators import bigquery_operator


YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'me',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': [''],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': YESTERDAY,
}

with airflow.DAG(
        'composer_test_dag',
        'catchup=False',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1)) as dag:

    bq_recent_questions_query = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
        task_id='bq_weather_query',
        bql="""
        SELECT owner_display_name, title, view_count
        FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions`
        ORDER BY view_count DESC
        LIMIT 100
        """,
        use_legacy_sql=False)
```

Is this the correct way?
How can i get the query results from this?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use Airflow/Composer? It's hard, complex and expensive. Another option is using Cloud Scheduler + Cloud Build. Much easier..and cheaper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BigQueryOperator` is generally used to execute a query in BigQuery and then load the result to another BigQuery table (transform operation). I assume you're trying to select 3 columns from a BigQuery public table and load to another table. So provide `destination_dataset_table` in BigQueryOperator.

Please note the following:

1. The stackoverflow.posts_questions table is very large, and even if you use LIMIT it will still scan the entire table. So beware of the cost.
2. Use `sql` param instead of `bql` as it is no longer used.

Comment: Thanks!
 destination_dataset_table in BigQueryOperator >> by giving this field, a new view / table be created with the query results?

Comment: Yes, it creates a table. The implementation for creating `view` instead of table using BigQueryOperator is also available here: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/77eb492b9cf279071d6123e4f0064363ed2b47b3/airflow/gcp/operators/bigquery.py#L696 so you can refer that code and copy  the implementation to your codebase if you need a view instead of table.

Comment: The behavior of when to create a new table can be configured with the [`create_disposition`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/rest/Shared.Types/CreateDisposition) parameter. By default this parameter is set to `CREATE_IF_NEEDED`, which will do what you describe. Please take also a look into the related parameter [`write_disposition`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/rest/Shared.Types/CreateDisposition). By default it is set to `WRITE_EMPTY`, which will only write to a table if it is empty or has just been created.